# error when use ‘git push ’ in gitlabci.yaml

Tags: git, gitlab, sh, gitlab-ci

When I use `.gitlabci.yaml` to run the `commit.sh` it show errors when it come to `git push`.
Any idea please ?

-------.gitlabci.yaml ------

```
dist:
stage: dist
tags:
    - vasdev-jenkins
script:
    - sh ./ci/commit.sh
    - ls -lah
only:
    - feature/gitlabci
    - develop
dependencies:
    - build
```

-----commit.sh----

```
#!/bin/bash

git config --global user.email "xxx@xx.com"
git config --global user.name "xxx"
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin $DEPLOY_TOKEN_URL
git branch -D develop_test || true
git fetch origin
git checkout -b develop_test origin/develop_test -f
git checkout develop_test

mv -f dist/* ./


rm -rf dist

git add .
git commit -am "$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
git push origin develop_jenkins
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you can check if the same push done manually on the GitLab job runner machine would work.

Second, check if a credential helper is set, by adding to your script, before the push:

```
git config credential.helper
```

The wrong credentials might have been cached.

If you are using https://username:password@remote//myrepo

- make sure 2FA is not activated
- make sure to use a token instead of the account password